# Imagebutton displays in design view but not in virtual device and now it also doesn't run showing failed linking

Tags: android

[image]

I have created a background and then created an imagebutton on top of it.
The imagebutton displays properly in design view.
But when i compile it it gives me following error:

```
Android resource linking failed
D:\Android Apps\BirdJumper\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:12: error: resource drawable/play (aka com.singularity.birdjumper:drawable/play) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Previously it used to run and show blank image button so both are my issues.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to clean the project and rebuild???